# Why isn't my multidimensional array correctly initialized and/or returned?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having the following problem:
I have this function where I pass a query result($matches_lines) as argument. In my function I get all the data I need from the query result and I'm trying to store it in a multidimensional array. My code is as follows:

```
function check_matches($matches_lines, $minage, $maxage, $actual_persontype){

    $result = array(array());
    $count = 0;

    foreach($matches_lines as $lines){

        $match_user = $lines["signup_username"];
        $match_birth = $lines["signup_birth"];
        $match_city = $lines["signup_city"];
        $match_gender = $lines["signup_gender"];
        $match_os = $lines["signup_os"];
        $match_persontype = $lines["signup_persontype"];

        if("some condition I want to verify"){

            $new_add = array($match_user, $match_birth, $match_city, $match_gender, $match_os, $match_persontype);
            array_push($result[$count], $new_add);
            $count = $count+1;  
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I call my function simply doing:

```
$matches_found = check_matches($matches_lines, $minage, $maxage, $actual_persontype);
```

I don't get errors by doing this, but when I try echoing one line

```
echo $matches_found[0][0];
```

I get a "HP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0".

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: var_dump($matches_found) returns "array(0) { }"

while var_dump($matches_lines) returns

object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(277) "SELECT s.signup_username, s.signup_birth, s.signup_city, s.signup_gender, s.signup_os, s.signup_persontype
 FROM signups s
 WHERE s.signup_username <> 'leonardo' && s.signup_city = 'Torino' && s.signup_os = 'Windows'" }

Comment: Also, if you cannot give us the condition, check again of the condition really matches at least one line. If you can provide it please do so.

Comment: `array_push` takes its first argument (an array) by reference. `$result[$count]` is undefined (`null`) after `$count = 0`, so it won't work. You can't push items onto null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem of your code definitely lies in your condition.** It matches no line and therefore the result contains no values for the inner array.
If there are no matches, you result will look like this:

```
$matches_found = [
    0 => [/*This array does not contain an index 0, because it is empty*/]
];
```

Therefore the call `$matches_found[0][0]` throws an error for the second `0`, because the inner array is empty.

Since you did not provide the condition we can not help you with fixing it.

The reason I can tell that this is the error is, that your code behind the condition contains an error and you said *I don't get errors*. Therefore it is never executed.

The line `array_push($result[$count], $new_add)` expects the first parameter `$result[$count]` to be an array. This is true for the first iteration, because you initialize `$result` with `[[]]`. For the second call with `$count = 1` there will be no field in `$result` with the index `1`. You will therefore either get an "*Undefined offset: 1*" error or "*function array_push expects parameter 1 to be of type array. null given*" error.

This can be fixed by using the native PHP handling for appending values to an array:

```
$result[] = [$new_add];
```

`$result[] =` will handle the appending of a new element and `[$new_add]` is an array that contains one element, the new row. If you do not need it to be wrapped in an extra array (`$new_add` is an array itself already) you can omit the brackets around it.

Note, that in order to let this work correctly you have to initialize `$result` with `$result = [];` instead of `$result = [[]];` ( or `array()` instead of `array(array())`).

PHP will then take care of the new indices itself. You can remove the `$count` variable.